# Template Overloading Behaves Differently Inside a Template Class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, template-specialization

In the following code yields ([LiveExample](https://ideone.com/PaR7lv)):

> Class template pointer
>
> Class template pointer
>
> Template pointer
>
> Template array with size 10

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <class TVar>
class CVar
{
public:
    void classTemplate(TVar *) const
    {
        std::cout << "Class template pointer\n";
    }

    template<unsigned sz>
    void classTemplate(TVar(&)[sz]) const
    {
         std::cout << "Class template array with size " << sz << "\n";
    }

};

template<typename T>
void regTemplate(T)
{
    std::cout << "Template pointer\n";
}

template<typename T, unsigned sz> void regTemplate(T(&)[sz])
{
    std::cout << "Template array with size " << sz << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int test[10] = {};

  CVar<unsigned> *cFoo = new CVar<unsigned>();
  cFoo->classTemplate(&test[0]);
  cFoo->classTemplate(test);

  regTemplate(&test[0]);
  regTemplate(test);
}
```

1. Why when I overload the template in the class, it cannot resolve the desired functionality - that is, `cFoo->classTemplate(test);` is called, then the response will be `Class template array with size 10`?
2. How do I achieve my desired result in 1 without changing `cFoo->classTemplate(test);`? Note that `void CVar<TVar>::classTemplate(TVar(&)[sz]) const` may change if needed

Answer (score 2):

Other things equal, overload resolution prefers non-templates over templates. In `classTemplate` case, one overload is a function template while the other is a non-template member function.

In `regTemplate` case, both are function templates: the one taking an array is chosen because it's more specialized. Indeed, if you change the first overload to take `T*`, the call becomes ambiguous.

Comment: So that explains why, and my first thought is to add a Template to `void classTemplate(TVar *) const;`, so that both functions can be treated equally. However, I appear to just be getting compile errors.

Comment: You can write a simple wrapper that takes a pointer in its constructor, and take that wrapper as a parameter in place of `TVar*`. This will make it a user-defined conversion, which has a lower rank. That'll break certain calls that may have worked before - e.g. passing in an object of a class that provides `operator unsigned*`.